# Issue on iou-cordapp-v2 under load with corda.notary.validating

Tags: corda

First I cloned https://github.com/roger3cev/iou-cordapp-v2. Then I changed Gradle to

```
advertisedServices = ["corda.notary.validating"]
```

We notice under load the following exceptions for the notary and node A:

```
[WARN ] 2017-07-25T23:01:48,505 [Node thread] flow.[61312ffc-4464-418a-a6e1-8e0700935243].run - Terminated by unexpected exception
net.corda.core.flows.FlowSessionException: Counterparty flow on CN=NodeA,O=NodeA,L=London,C=UK has completed without sending a java.util.ArrayList
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.confirmReceiveType(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:370) ~[node-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.waitForMessage(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:335) ~[node-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.access$waitForMessage(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:37) ~[node-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.sendAndReceive(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:484) ~[node-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowStateMachine$DefaultImpls.sendAndReceive$default(FlowStateMachine.kt:61) ~[core-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.sendAndReceive(FlowLogic.kt:88) ~[core-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.flows.FetchDataFlow.call(FetchDataFlow.kt:109) ~[core-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.flows.FetchDataFlow.call(FetchDataFlow.kt:32) ~[core-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:164) ~[core-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.flows.ResolveTransactionsFlow.downloadDependencies(ResolveTransactionsFlow.kt:169) ~[core-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.flows.ResolveTransactionsFlow.call(ResolveTransactionsFlow.kt:99) ~[core-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.flows.ResolveTransactionsFlow.call(ResolveTransactionsFlow.kt:32) ~[core-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:164) ~[core-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.transactions.ValidatingNotaryFlow.resolveTransaction(ValidatingNotaryFlow.kt:61) ~[node-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.transactions.ValidatingNotaryFlow.validateTransaction(ValidatingNotaryFlow.kt:49) ~[node-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.transactions.ValidatingNotaryFlow.receiveAndVerifyTx(ValidatingNotaryFlow.kt:34) ~[node-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.flows.NotaryFlow$Service.call(NotaryFlow.kt:104) ~[core-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.flows.NotaryFlow$Service.call(NotaryFlow.kt:99) ~[core-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:109) [node-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:37) [node-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1067) [quasar-core-0.7.6-jdk8.jar:0.7.6]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:767) [quasar-core-0.7.6-jdk8.jar:0.7.6]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) [quasar-core-0.7.6-jdk8.jar:0.7.6]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) [quasar-core-0.7.6-jdk8.jar:0.7.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:69) [node-0.12.1.jar:?]
[WARN ] 2017-07-25T23:01:48,531 [Node thread] statemachine.StateMachineManager.onExistingSessionMessage - Received a session message for unknown session: SessionData(recipientSessionId=413231130597723617, payload=[SignedTransaction
[WARN ] 2017-07-25T23:05:45,924 [Node thread] flow.[91326f02-b7cf-4366-8dd7-c5a7def83744].run - Terminated by unexpected exception
net.corda.core.flows.FlowSessionException: Counterparty flow on CN=Controller,O=R3,OU=corda,L=London,C=UK had an internal error and has terminated
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.erroredEnd(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:384) ~[node-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.confirmReceiveType(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:367) ~[node-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.waitForMessage(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:335) ~[node-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.access$waitForMessage(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:37) ~[node-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.sendAndReceive(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:484) ~[node-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.sendAndReceiveWithRetry$core_main(FlowLogic.kt:107) ~[core-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.flows.NotaryFlow$Client.call(NotaryFlow.kt:188) ~[core-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.flows.NotaryFlow$Client.call(NotaryFlow.kt:35) ~[core-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:164) ~[core-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.flows.FinalityFlow.notariseAndRecord(FinalityFlow.kt:80) ~[core-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.flows.FinalityFlow.call(FinalityFlow.kt:62) ~[core-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.flows.FinalityFlow.call(FinalityFlow.kt:35) ~[core-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:164) ~[core-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.iou.flow.IOUSettleFlow$Initiator.call(IOUSettleFlow.kt:97) ~[iou-cordapp-v2-3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.iou.flow.IOUSettleFlow$Initiator.call(IOUSettleFlow.kt:26) ~[iou-cordapp-v2-3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:109) [node-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:37) [node-0.12.1.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1067) [quasar-core-0.7.6-jdk8.jar:0.7.6]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:767) [quasar-core-0.7.6-jdk8.jar:0.7.6]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) [quasar-core-0.7.6-jdk8.jar:0.7.6]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) [quasar-core-0.7.6-jdk8.jar:0.7.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:69) [node-0.12.1.jar:?]
[WARN ] 2017-07-25T23:06:18,695 [HikariPool-3 housekeeper] pool.HikariPool.run - HikariPool-3 - Retrograde clock change detected (housekeeper delta=26s916ms), soft-evicting connections from pool.
[WARN ] 2017-07-25T23:06:44,291 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] pool.HikariPool.run - HikariPool-1 - Retrograde clock change detected (housekeeper delta=26s918ms), soft-evicting connections from pool.
[WARN ] 2017-07-25T23:06:44,717 [HikariPool-2 housekeeper] pool.HikariPool.run - HikariPool-2 - Retrograde clock change detected (housekeeper delta=26s917ms), soft-evicting connections from pool.
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no clue what you're trying to ask here.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, sending ~3000 transactions (Cash transfer) will usually end up with many `statemachine.StateMachineManager.onExistingSessionMessage - Received a session message for unknown session: SessionData(r` messages in the log

Answer (score 0):

We've opened an issue here to investigate the issue of notary performance under load: https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/1120.